# How to get all attributes from an Autocad block using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

So, I´ve been trying  to iterate through all blocks in an Autocad drawing to find a block named "FL01", That I can do, But I also want to get all his attributes to concatenate some of them into a string. Here is the code:

```
Dim cellValue As String
cellValue = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value
' Converte o valor em uma string
cellValue = CStr(cellValue)
Dim acadApp As Object
Set acadApp = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")

' Abre um documento DWG
Dim acadDoc As Object
Set acadDoc = acadApp.Documents.Open(cellValue)
' Itera sobre os blocos do documento
Dim minhaColecao As Collection
Set minhaColecao = New Collection
Dim block As Object
Dim atts() As Variant
For Each block In acadDoc.Blocks
    If block.Name = "FL01" Then
    atts = block.GetAttributes ' The error is right Here
    Dim i As Long
    Dim aux As String
    For i = LBound(atts) To UBound(atts)
        If atts(i).TagString = "TIPO" Then
            aux = atts(i).TextString
        ElseIf atts(i).TagString = "SEQ-1" Then
            aux = aux & "-" & atts(i).TextString
        ElseIf atts(i).TagString = "SEQ-2" Then
            aux = aux & "-" & atts(i).TextString
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    minhaColecao.Add aux
    End If
    ' Faça algo com o bloco
    Next block
Range("A1").Select
Dim item As Variant
For Each item In minhaColecao
    ActiveCell.Value = item
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select ' Move para a próxima linha
Next item
' Fecha o documento
acadDoc.Close False
```

By the way, cell B5 is where the path to the .dwg file is. The whole plan was to concatenate specific attributes, add them into a collection and then write that collection into an excel file.

When I run the code, It claims that the "block" does not accept the "GetAttributes" method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is iterating over the AutoCAD Blocks Collection, which contains containers such as Layouts and Block *Definitions*.

Instead, you will need to iterate over the content of the Layout container (and Block Definition container if you're interested in nested attributed blocks) until you encounter attributed block *references* against which the `GetAttributes` method may be used.

Something along the lines of:

```vb
For Each block In acadDoc.Blocks
    If block.IsLayout Then
        For Each obj In block
            If obj.ObjectName = "AcDbBlockReference" Then
                If obj.Name = "FL01" Then
                    atts = obj.GetAttributes
                    ...
```